# Asp .Net Print a remote image to local print

Tags: asp.net, image, printing, local, remoting

I've a small web application (asp.net 4.0 + c#) to create picture (5MB each usually)

I've a laptop connected, by usb, to a local printer (not on the network) and I'd like to print the remote image to it.

**Example:** I open the page Print.aspx and I have an Image control (so the remote url is www.mysite.com/img/imagetoprint.jpg)  and below it a button. Clicking the button should open my local printer...in the quickest way possible.

Piece of code please?
Suggestions? Examples?

Thanks in advance

Max

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: public void PrintImmagine(string value)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "~/Images/Final.jpg";
        p.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
        p.Start();
    }

Comment: the exception is no application is associated with the specified file for this operation